# React Native 0.70 Should I have to use ruby 2.7.5 only For MAC M1

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QoVwg.png)Currently what is the problem ruby was preinstalled with MAC M1.

After watching many tutorials I have managed to install ruby using homebrew.

but with homebrew I have manage to install ruby 2.7.6 (which was stable version).

Now, When I init Reactnative project what I do when project file is download and installing dependency I used to change the Gemfile ruby version 2.7.5 -> 2.7.6

And project configure properly.

Should it effect any other error in future?

> While working react-native firebase setup on IOS showing issue regarding the 'FlipperKit/FlipperClient.h' file not found

Though I can see the FlipperKit pods an all.

Suggest me does my steps affecting this kind of problem ?
Thanks.

ruby 2.7.6 with homebrew -> now, while installing other things getting error for IOS.

Comment: when you first initiate the project without changing anything does it build and run?

Comment: The project is running properly, but the thing is though I have followed the Reactnative firebase installation steps and I can see the Pods files there still seeing these kinds of errors.